Can't get update data from metatrader5 in Python
I want to get stock data from mt5 in Python, but the last 12 candles aren't available.
My code is like below:
from_date = datetime.now()
# Extract n Ticks before now
rates = mt5.copy_rates_from(symbol, timeframe, from_date, number_of_data)
# Transform Tuple into a DataFrame
df_rates = pd.DataFrame(rates)
# Convert number format of the date into date format
df_rates["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_rates["time"], unit="s")
df_rates = df_rates.set_index("time")
print(df_rates)
print(datetime.now)

when print the exit is like below:
0   2024-05-30 21:45:00  1.08385  1.08390  ...          339       2            


1   2024-05-30 22:00:00  1.08368  1.08368  ...          322       1            

2   2024-05-30 22:15:00  1.08354  1.08364  ...          362       1            

3   2024-05-30 22:30:00  1.08352  1.08354  ...          357       2            

4   2024-05-30 22:45:00  1.08296  1.08316  ...          528       2            

..                  ...      ...      ...  ...          ...     ...          ...

495 2024-06-07 03:00:00  1.08917  1.08917  ...          245       2            

496 2024-06-07 03:15:00  1.08888  1.08908  ...          230       2            

497 2024-06-07 03:30:00  1.08878  1.08889  ...          167       2            

498 2024-06-07 03:45:00  1.08885  1.08925  ...          281       2            

499 ***2024-06-07 04:00:00***  1.08895  1.08908  ...          300       2            

[500 rows x 8 columns]

***2024-06-07 07:44:35.858691***

Please help me.

maybe you have wrong time.  Maybe you use local time and it may need UTC

thanks for your answer. but i change my local time to utc.the problem is still not resolved

Have you confirmed that the contents of rates contains the data you expect?
